# How to alter a table and add onDelete cascade constraint sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I am using room database I've a table in which I forgot to add `onDelete = CASCADE`

Previous version

`@Entity(indices = {@Index(value = {"info_id"})}, foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = StudentClass.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "info_id"))`

What I want now

`@Entity(indices = {@Index(value = {"info_id"})}, foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = StudentClass.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "info_id", onDelete = CASCADE))`

I am trying to migrate the database

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            database.execSQL("What should I do here to add onDelete = CASCADE");
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok finally I found the solution

```
database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE attendance_temp(attendanceId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, time INTEGER NOT NULL, student_id INTEGER, student_name TEXT , roll_number INTEGER, image_path TEXT, info_id INTEGER, present INTEGER , CONSTRAINT fk_class_info FOREIGN KEY (info_id) REFERENCES class_info(id) ON DELETE CASCADE)");
database.execSQL("INSERT INTO attendance_temp SELECT * FROM Attendance");
database.execSQL("DROP TABLE Attendance");
database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE attendance_temp RENAME TO Attendance");
database.execSQL("CREATE INDEX index_Attendance_info_id ON Attendance(info_id)");
```

Also change the schema in entity class to

```
@Entity(indices = {@Index(value = {"info_id"})}, foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = StudentClass.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "info_id", onDelete = CASCADE))
```

The sequence is important.

Comment: Wow, that's unfortunately so painful :(

Answer (score 2):

SQLite does not completely support SQL ALTER TABLE standard:

> Only the RENAME TABLE, ADD COLUMN, and RENAME COLUMN variants of the
>   ALTER TABLE command are supported. Other kinds of ALTER TABLE
>   operations such as DROP COLUMN, ALTER COLUMN, ADD CONSTRAINT, and so
>   forth are omitted.

[Source](https://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html)

So the only way to add a constraint is recreating the table and copying the data of the old one to the new one:

```
// 1. Rename your table
database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Entity RENAME TO Entity_old")
// 2. Recreate the same entity, but now with the constraint
database.execSQL("""
    CREATE TABLE Entity(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
        parentId INTEGER, 
        someField STRING, 
        CONSTRAINT fk_Entity_entityId_EntityParent_id FOREIGN KEY (entityId) REFERENCES EntityParent(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    )
""")
// 3. Copy the data from the old table
database.execSQL("INSERT INTO Entity SELECT * FROM Entity_old")
// 4. Delete old table
database.execSQL("DROP TABLE Entity_old")
// 5. Recreate the indices
database.execSQL("CREATE INDEX index_Entity_id ON Entity(id)")
```